# ubuntu 19.04 stops working

Tags: 19.04

I am facing a strange problem with my laptop, running with Ubuntu 19.04. Since today morning, suddenly at one time, my laptop stops working after a series of symptoms like increase in brightness to the maximum level (I prefer to work with low brightness), then laptop keypad stops working. I am able to move the cursor on the screen but the click is not working). To get rid of this, I use to remove the battery then again restart the laptop. 
I don't understand why this is happening. Is there some issue with laptop hardware or problem with Ubuntu? I seriously need help as it is happening with every 2-3 hours now. Thank you.

Some part of date of /var/log/syslog is as below at the time when the problem apper:

```
    Jul  1 10:30:56 jagannath systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath gnome-shell[1749]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to update overlay icon
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath gnome-shell[1749]: [AppIndicatorSupport-FATAL] unable to update overlay icon
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
    Jul  1 10:30:57 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
    Jul  1 10:30:59 jagannath PackageKit: refresh-cache transaction /896_abaeccdb from uid 1000 finished with failed after 3113ms
    Jul  1 10:31:00 jagannath systemd[1]: man-db.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:31:00 jagannath systemd[1]: Started Daily man-db regeneration.
    Jul  1 10:31:01 jagannath PackageKit: refresh-cache transaction /897_dbdacaed from uid 1000 finished with failed after 2480ms
    Jul  1 10:31:04 jagannath PackageKit: refresh-cache transaction /898_caeeadeb from uid 1000 finished with failed after 2460ms
    Jul  1 10:31:05 jagannath systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:31:16 jagannath kernel: [  697.455938] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
    Jul  1 10:31:16 jagannath kernel: [  697.513943] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
    Jul  1 10:31:16 jagannath kernel: [  697.561852] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  697.647732] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  697.762461] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 16874 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  697.810466] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 11021 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  697.858468] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 14455 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  697.906475] raid6: avx2x2   xor()  8755 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  697.954481] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 12672 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.002508] raid6: avx2x1   xor()  7148 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.050497] raid6: sse2x4   gen()  8651 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.098583] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  3577 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.146514] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  5931 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.194543] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  3870 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.242513] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  4213 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.290513] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  3743 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.290515] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 16874 MB/s
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.290516] raid6: .... xor() 11021 MB/s, rmw enabled
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.290518] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.317932] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath kernel: [  698.391836] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath os-prober: debug: /dev/sda2: is active swap
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath 05efi: debug: Not on UEFI platform
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath 10freedos: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a FAT partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath 10qnx: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath macosx-prober: debug: /dev/sda3 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:17 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath 20microsoft: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a MS partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath 30utility: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a FAT partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath 83haiku: debug: /dev/sda3 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris on mounted /dev/sda3
    Jul  1 10:31:18 jagannath os-prober: debug: running /usr/lib/os-probes/50mounted-tests on /dev/sda4
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: mounted using GRUB ext2 filesystem driver
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 05efi: debug: Not on UEFI platform
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10freedos
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 10freedos: debug: /dev/sda4 is not a FAT partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/10qnx
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 10qnx: debug: /dev/sda4 is not a QNX4 partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20macosx
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath macosx-prober: debug: /dev/sda4 is not an HFS+ partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 20microsoft: debug: /dev/sda4 is not a MS partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/30utility
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 30utility: debug: /dev/sda4 is not a FAT partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/40lsb
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/70hurd
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/80minix
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/83haiku
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 83haiku: debug: /dev/sda4 is not a BeFS partition: exiting
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90linux-distro
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/90solaris
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath 50mounted-tests: debug: running subtest /usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/efi
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath systemd[1]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:31:19 jagannath systemd[1573]: var-lib-os\x2dprober-mount.mount: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:31:20 jagannath systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
    Jul  1 10:31:21 jagannath systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath NetworkManager[960]: <info>  [1561957285.8580] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath dbus-daemon[958]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=960 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath whoopsie[1302]: [10:31:25] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath dbus-daemon[958]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath whoopsie[1302]: [10:31:25] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath whoopsie[1302]: [10:31:25] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
    Jul  1 10:31:25 jagannath nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
    Jul  1 10:31:26 jagannath systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:31:26 jagannath whoopsie[1302]: [10:31:26] online
    Jul  1 10:31:35 jagannath systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:31:47 jagannath systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:31:47 jagannath systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
    Jul  1 10:31:48 jagannath systemd-resolved[775]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
    Jul  1 10:31:59 jagannath gnome-software[2284]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
    Jul  1 10:32:00 jagannath PackageKit: resolve transaction /899_baebdbac from uid 1000 finished with success after 517ms
    Jul  1 10:32:00 jagannath gnome-software[2284]: ignoring non-installed app GsApp: [0x7f65f010e850]#012kind:                desktop#012state:               available#012quirk:               provenance#012id:                  nemo.desktop#012unique-id:           system/package/ubuntu-disco-universe/desktop/nemo.desktop/*#012scope:               system#012bundle-kind:         package#012kudos:               my-language|hi-dpi-icon#012kudo-percentage:     40#012name:                Files#012pixbuf:              0x7f65e84dc520#012icon-kind:           stock#012icon-name:           org.gnome.Nautilus#012icon-prefix:         /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-disco-universe#012icon-kind:           cached#012icon-name:           budgie-desktop-common_org.gnome.Nautilus.png#012icon-prefix:         /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-disco-universe#012icon-kind:           remote#012version:             0.11.7#012summary:             Access and organize files#012description:         While this common budgie-desktop package can be installed manually, it is recommended that the binary packages budgie-desktop-minimal or budgie-desktop-environment be used to install working minimal or the recommended full budgie-desktop environment.#012#012This package provides common:   ubuntu and budgie-desktop gsettings overrides   make QT apps look like GTK+ apps   default icon-theme for GTK+ applications   Ubuntu Budgie plymouth branding#012source-00:           budgie-desktop-common#012source-01:           nemo#012source-id-00:        budgie-desktop-common;0.11.7;all;ubuntu-disco-universe#012source-id-01:        nemo;3.8.5-1build1;amd64;installed:ubuntu-disco-universe#012url{homepage}:       https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie#012license:             LicenseRef-free=https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing#012license-is-free:     yes#012management-plugin:   packagekit#012origin:              ubuntu-disco-universe#012origin-appstream:    ubuntu-disco-universe#012rating:              78#012review-rating:       [0:0]#012review-rating:       [1:2]#012review-rating:       [2:1]#012review-rating:       [3:0]#012review-rating:       [4:0]#012review-rating:       [5:8]#012reviews:             0#012provides:            0#012install-date:        1#012size-installed:      unknowable#012size-download:       4.7 MB#012category:            Utility#012category:            Core#012{appstream::source-file}: /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop#012{GnomeSoftware::Creator}: appstream
    Jul  1 10:32:01 jagannath gnome-software[2284]: hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
    Jul  1 10:32:01 jagannath systemd[1]: apt-daily.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:32:01 jagannath systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
    Jul  1 10:32:45 jagannath gnome-shell[1749]: g_environ_setenv: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
    Jul  1 10:32:45 jagannath dbus-daemon[1602]: [session uid=1000 pid=1602] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1749 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
    Jul  1 10:32:45 jagannath dbus-daemon[1602]: [session uid=1000 pid=1602] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
    Jul  1 10:32:46 jagannath dbus-daemon[958]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.606' (uid=1000 pid=5820 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
    Jul  1 10:32:46 jagannath systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
    Jul  1 10:32:46 jagannath dbus-daemon[958]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
    Jul  1 10:32:46 jagannath systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
    Jul  1 10:32:47 jagannath nautilus[5820]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
    Jul  1 10:33:16 jagannath dbus-daemon[1602]: [session uid=1000 pid=1602] Activating service name='org.gnome.evince.Daemon' requested by ':1.104' (uid=1000 pid=5852 comm="evince /home/jagannath/jagannath/phd/books/Brunner" label="/usr/bin/evince (enforce)")
    Jul  1 10:33:16 jagannath dbus-daemon[1602]: [session uid=1000 pid=1602] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evince.Daemon'
    Jul  1 10:33:16 jagannath systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:33:17 jagannath org.gnome.Nautilus[1602]: ! SyncTeX Error : No file?
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd-tmpfiles[5898]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:1] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd-tmpfiles[5898]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd-tmpfiles[5898]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:3] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd-tmpfiles[5898]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:4] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd-tmpfiles[5898]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:5] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/log → /run/speech-dispatcher/log; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd-tmpfiles[5898]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/spice-vdagentd.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/spice-vdagentd → /run/spice-vdagentd; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:34:59 jagannath systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
    Jul  1 10:35:03 jagannath gnome-shell[1749]: g_environ_setenv: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
    Jul  1 10:35:10 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: [5947:5947:0701/103510.358068:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(368)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
    Jul  1 10:35:23 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: [5947:5947:0701/103523.126239:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
    Jul  1 10:35:23 jagannath systemd-resolved[775]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
    Jul  1 10:35:23 jagannath systemd-resolved[775]: message repeated 2 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
    Jul  1 10:35:40 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: [5947:6017:0701/103540.793860:ERROR:latency_info.cc(149)] Surface::TakeLatencyInfoFromFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 102 is too big.
    Jul  1 10:35:49 jagannath anacron[3041]: Job `cron.daily' started
    Jul  1 10:35:49 jagannath anacron[6386]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2019-07-01
    Jul  1 10:35:51 jagannath cracklib: no dictionary update necessary.
    Jul  1 10:35:52 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: [5952:5956:0701/103552.685391:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
    Jul  1 10:35:56 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: [5947:6017:0701/103556.765588:ERROR:latency_info.cc(149)] Surface::TakeLatencyInfoFromFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 101 is too big.
    Jul  1 10:36:12 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: [5952:5956:0701/103612.705504:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
    Jul  1 10:36:27 jagannath anacron[3041]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
    Jul  1 10:37:03 jagannath PackageKit: daemon quit
    Jul  1 10:37:03 jagannath systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
    Jul  1 10:37:03 jagannath systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:40:50 jagannath anacron[3041]: Job `cron.weekly' started
    Jul  1 10:40:50 jagannath anacron[6833]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.weekly' to 2019-07-01
    Jul  1 10:40:50 jagannath anacron[3041]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
    Jul  1 10:40:50 jagannath anacron[3041]: Normal exit (2 jobs run)
    Jul  1 10:40:50 jagannath systemd[1]: anacron.service: Killing process 6840 (check-new-relea) with signal SIGKILL.
    Jul  1 10:40:50 jagannath systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
    Jul  1 10:43:02 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
    Jul  1 10:43:06 jagannath org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1749]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
```

To see my video card I used command `lspci -v | less` and its output is :

```
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) (
    prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
            Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 5500
            Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 56
            Memory at a9000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
            Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
            I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
            [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
            Capabilities: <access denied>
            Kernel driver in use: i915
            Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: That is unusual and rare. The problem occurs on none of my test hardware, all of which (including laptops) have uptimes measured in weeks or months at a time. Note the exact time of an occurrence, then look for clues in `/var/log/syslog` and `var/log/kern.log`. If you don't understand the logs, then post the relevant minutes of activity into your question. If nothing relevant is logged, then it's likely a hardware fault.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like a hardware error. You could run `dmesg -w` in a terminal. This will show kernel messages. If you see a lot of red messages, then also this will point to the likelyhood of hardware issues.

Comment: Thnak you @vanadium for your suggestion, I checked dmesg -w but it is not showing any red message. Does it mean no hardware issue?

Comment: Give us a little more info on your machine.  What video card is it using?

Comment: Hi @kc1di, I have added the info about video card. Please suggest further. Thank you.

Comment: The output related to "os-prober" are, I think, due to `grub-update`, and that is usually run following an `apt install` or similar, which might be from `unattended-upgrade` -- please check for that in `less /var/log/apt/history.log` and see if there are entries at around 10:31 am on the relevant day? Why that might cause the error is that it messes with kernel modules, and updated services -- depending on your settings related to apt -- might get replaced causing things to break until they're properly brought up in a reboot. Try disabling `unattended-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a number of issues related to this error message. Including slow wake up from sleeps. Long pauses in screen repaint. Long launch times for applications. The only sure fix I found was to completely purge the gnome-shell-extension-appindicator package and reboot. The system them becomes properly responsive again. I have no idea what visual flim flam this extension provides so I can certainly do without it. It is a shame that it is installed by default.

Comment: Hi @rogerjames99, thank you for your comment. I had asked this question in June 29 and still now I am facing this prblem in my laptop. Can you please guide me how to purge the gnome-shell-extension-appindicator package?

Comment: On Ubuntu I used.


```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

Comment: On Ubuntu I used.

`sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-extension-appindicator`

Comment: Third try. I still cannot work out how markdown works here!